# Maximizing iterations of finding circular successive differences

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

*From a competition we had in comp sci:*

Given four integers, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ take repeated absolute differences including $|a-d|$ until you reach all zeros.  At each iteration,

$a' \gets |b-a|$

$b' \gets |c-a|$

$c' \gets |d-c|$

$d' \gets |a-d|$

For example, starting with $(-7,1,5,-16)$, this produces the following $6$ iterations:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d \\ \hline 
 -7 & 1& 5 &-16  \\ \hline
8 & 4& 21 & 9 \\ \hline
4 & 17& 12 & 1 \\ \hline
13 & 5 & 11 & 3 \\ \hline
8 & 6 & 8 & 10\\ \hline
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\ \hline
0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
The winner was the one to find a 4-tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ that produced the most iterations (I think the best found was around 26 iterations).
The competition has been over for a while, but we all went about it the same way, by randomly generating 4-tubples and keeping track of our best.

> Is there a more elegant or closed form solution to finding a 4-tuple that maximizes these iterations?

Note that because we were coding and using *int* datatypes, there was a minimum integer value of $-32,76$8 and maximum of $32,768$.  Even with this constraint, brute-force searching would take an astronomical amount of time.

Comment: It's curious that almost all starting points end very quickly; in particular, exactly half the time, the length of the sequence is $4$. For the rare long sequences, notice that the penultimate values are multiples of a "medium-range" power of $2$, like $[128,128,128,128]$. In binary, $128_2 = 000000010000000$. Try working backwards from there.